# Loop through order_id

Tags: c#, logic

I have 2 tables:

Table A

```
    order_id | name | address
    --------------------------------------
    123      |Jim   |123 Spooner St
    124      |Peter |176 Applecove Rd
    125      |Bob   |250 Quail Nest Circle
```

Table B

```
    order_id | model | quantity
    ---------------------------
    123      |BK-100 |1
    124      |DC-890 |2
    124      |MP-450 |1
    125      |GG-250 |3
```

What I'm trying to do is loop through the order_id and get ALL information from it.
Right now I have it looping through order_id's in Table A just fine. My issue comes in where I'm linking Table B order_id to Table A. It's coming out like:

```
    order_id:
    123
    name:
    ~~~~~
    Address:
    ~~~~~~~~
    order_id:
    123
    model:
    ~~~~~~
    quantity:
    ~
```

Next order

```
    order_id:
    124
    name:
    ~~~~~
    Address:
    ~~~~~~~~
    order_id:
    124
    model:
    ~~~~~~
    quantity:
    ~
```

Next order

```
    order_id:
    125
    name:
    ~~~~~
    Address:
    ~~~~~~~~
    order_id:
    124
    model:
    ~~~~~~
    quantity:
    ~
```

So it is getting all the order_id's on Table B but it isn't linking them to the ones in Table A.

Comment: What do you mean by 'isn't linking them to the ones in Table A'? Do you want order_id, name, address, model, quantity in one go?

Comment: What should be your standard output format??

Comment: What I need is all the order_id's in Table B that are in Table A to be put with the Table A contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through `Table A`. For each row get the `order_id` and query `Table B` with this `order_id`. This way you will get all related orders from `Table B` for each order in `Table A`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a query as below, if you are getting your values from MS SQL:

```
Select A.order_id, A.Name, A.Address, B.Model, B.Quantity from Table A, Table B where A.order_id=B.order_id
```